# make error at Building C object common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/demo_system.c.o

Tags: riscv32

I'm trying to builds the software that I can later use as memory content for the Ibex
running in the demo system.

After the following commands:
mkdir -p sw/build
pushd sw/build
cmake ..
make

"make" gives me the:
[  3%] Building C object common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/demo_system.c.o
/bin/sh: 1: riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/build.make:76: common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/demo_system.c.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:209: common/CMakeFiles/common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

I'm following this tutorial:
https://github.com/lowRISC/ibex-demo-system

Comment: It seems you haven't installed the cross-compiler correctly, or it's not in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new in Linux. Where can I find the cross-compiler and how can I add it to the PATH?